# How do I make a folder accessible on a WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I've uploaded a folder to a WordPress site. I'd like to access it e.g `http://my.url.com/myfolder`

The problem is WordPress' `.htaccess` file which assumes I'm trying to load a page or post and doesn't load the folder.

If you were in my boots, what would you do to overcome this situation?

My `.htaccess` looks like so:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I think this is more of a question for ServerFault -- since it has to do with server permissions.

Comment: oh cool! a sister site. Thanks Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

checks if the requested url is an existing file or directory and only if that is not the case, wordpress jumps in and tries to interpret the url via index.php.

Try setting a different chmod (Permission) for your folder (e.g. 777).
Also try adding a / to the end of your url http://my.url.com/myfolder/

Comment: thanks stefanw. as it turns out, i should be in bed because i was hitting the wrong folder. But your explanation of those 2 lines helped me a lot.